# Is there a way to setup a timed or polling route in Apache Camel only using the Spring DSL?

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I have a nice simple route that uses Camel's ftpcomponent:

```
<camelContext id="myroute" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="file:///outgoing"/>
        <to uri="ftp://user@randomftpsite/test/?password=password"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Is there a way to have this route triggered, say once an hour, right in the Spring DSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
<camelContext id="myContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="myRoute">
        <from uri="file:///outgoing?delay=1h"/> 
        <to uri="ftp://user@randomftpsite/test/?password=password"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

File can do that directly. You should take a look here: http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Comment: The file component is documented at: http://camel.apache.org/file2 as file is for the old file component in Camel 1.x which is EOL.

Comment: Also you can use shorthand for delay, eg delay=1h for 1 hour, which is maybe easier to read

Comment: Thanks for the comments Claus, I edited my answer to reflect them.